# How to compare two different values of different functions or same function?

Tags: javascript

I have two variables `index_1` and `index_2` of different function and I have to compare that. Is that correct method or I can something else

Currently, I am not satisfied with this code for comparison because every time i get same value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var index_1 = '';
       var index_2 = '';

        $('#spin-now').click(function(){

        $(".spin-box-1").jCarouselLite({
            auto: 200,
            speed: 200,
            visible: 1,
            vertical: true,
            easing: "easeOutBounce",
                afterEnd: function(a) {
                     var index_1 = $(a[0]).index();
                     store_index_1(index_1);    
                }
        });

        $(".spin-box-2").jCarouselLite({
            auto: 225,
            speed: 225,
            visible: 1,
            vertical: true,
            easing: "easeOutBounce",
                afterEnd: function(a) {
                     var index_2 = $(a[0]).index();
                     store_index_1(index_2);
                }
        });       

    });

            function store_index_1(x){
                data_index_1 = x;
                data_index_2 = data_index_1 ;
                if(data_index_2 == data_index_1){
                    //alert('same');
                }
               else{
                  alert('different');
                }


                  console.log('outside'+''+data_index_1+''+data_index_2);  
            }

//console.log(data_index_1);


});
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You assign `data_index_2 = data_index_1 ;` and then have `if(data_index_2 == data_index_1)`? Why? (The if test will always be true unless `data_index_1` was `NaN`.)

Comment: @nnnnnn i just trying to store value in temporary variable, so that i can compare with next (store_index_1(index_2);) variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I think this should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation)

You defined 2 global variables, so if you're going to use them, then save your first index of `.spin-box-1` in **index_1** and `.spin-box-2` in **index_2**, and then call a '*compare*' function (your `store_index_1`).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var index_1 = '';
       var index_2 = '';

        $('#spin-now').click(function(){

        $(".spin-box-1").jCarouselLite({
            auto: 200,
            speed: 200,
            visible: 1,
            vertical: true,
            easing: "easeOutBounce",
                afterEnd: function(a) {
                     index_1 = $(a[0]).index(); //index_1 is your global
                }
        });

        $(".spin-box-2").jCarouselLite({
            auto: 225,
            speed: 225,
            visible: 1,
            vertical: true,
            easing: "easeOutBounce",
                afterEnd: function(a) {
                     index_2 = $(a[0]).index(); //index_2 is your global
                }
        }); 
        compare(); //index_1 and index2 should be set by this line.

    });

            function compare(){
                if(index_1 == index_2){
                    alert('same');
                }
               else{
                  alert('different');
                }

                  console.log('outside'+''+index_1+''+index_2);  
            }

//rest of your code 

});
```

The thing with your `store_index_1(x)` function is that it will always be true because you are comparing 2 equal values:

```
data_index_2 = data_index_1 ;
if(data_index_2 == data_index_1)
```

That's kind of nonsense so i'm confused about what are you trying to do.
And again, sorry for the 'answer' 'cause I can't comment yet.

Comment: dude your way of solution is correct but ur not passing value through function. I am getting blank value and alert same every time

Comment: Exactly, i'm not passing any value because we're working with global variables. At first, **index_1** and **index_2** will be the same value. But I realized some mistakes (I forgot to delete the 'var' from index_2) and I think that the call to _'compare'_ should be just at the end. I am going to edit my answer.. you tell me if it works (everybody is learning here (Y))